# Connect to VM running on the same computer without LAN

Tags: networking, ip, vmware, lan

I have a windows 2003 VM running on my windows xp machine.
The machine name of the VM is itdom.domain.com
The windows xp host machine is disconnected from the LAN.
I want to be able to connect to the VM from the host and vice versa using there computer names. For example the URL  http://itlab.domain:7080/domainsm must be accessible from the host computer.

Is there any configuration that I can do on any of the machine to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have no physical network connection doesn't stop you setting up networking on the host and guest machines. One way of doing this is to add an IP address to the host machine's physical network port and create a bridged network on that port so that the guest can also see it.

You don't say which VM technology you are using, but in many of them you can setup an internal network between the host and guest. All you need to do then is edit each hosts file to add a hostname for the IP address of the other machine. You may also need to configure firewalls to allow access between the two.

No doubt there are also other ways to achieve this.